# Can a DFA be designed to accept any language?

Tags: dfa

The answer given by our instructor to this question is FALSE.

However, I think it has to be true. Take this DFA that accepts sigma star.

- Q -> {s_1}
- q_0 -> s_1
- sigma -> {a, b}
- F -> {s_1}
- delta -> {s_1[sigma] -> s_1}

[image]

That means this language necessarily accepts (sigma star) star, This is the set of all languages, including non-regular ones like {a^nb^n | n > 1}. It seems to me then that non-regular languages would be accepted as they are a subset of the language this DFA describes.

It seems to me like this DFA would accept any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recognizing a language implies *rejecting* strings that don't belong in that language, not just accepting strings that do belong. The fact that you can build an automaton that accepts every string doesn't mean you can build an automaton that accepts the *specific* strings you need to accept and rejects everything else.

This remains true with your edit; the language accepted by an automaton is the set of all words the automaton accepts. Arbitrary subsets of that set do not count as languages accepted by that automaton. ("The language accepted by an automaton" and "the language recognized by an automaton" are synonymous.)

Comment: I accidentally mixed up the words recognizing and accepting. I was deliberating on this problem for awhile and started getting my thoughts mixed up. The question asks if a DFA can "accept" any language.

Comment: @Antithesis: Answer expanded. It sounds like you have your definitions mixed up.

Comment: That makes sense, I took Formal Language Theory a few years ago, but now taking a compilers course in graduate school. Some of the math has been mixed up.

Out of curiosity, how is ambiguity dealt with? i.e., how do you know some DFA computes sigma star vs some other language?

Comment: @Antithesis: What ambiguity? A DFA is deterministic.

Comment: The ambiguity of what language a DFA is computing. If you have some DFA as a computing system, it seems like it would be really hard to determine if the accepted language is sigma star. Of course it fairly obvious if you have the state diagram.

Comment: @Antithesis: Within the context of formal language theory, "ambiguity" means a specific thing entirely unrelated to what you seem to be trying to say. As for how to determine what language a DFA computes, that depends on what your notion of "knowing" the language is. There are [DFA-to-regex algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions), if you would consider having a regex for the language to be "knowing" the language.

Answer (score 1):

Σ* isn't the set of all languages.  It's the *single* language that includes all strings.

DFAs cannot recognize any language that require an infinite number of states.   For example, a^nb^n (the language containing an equal number of a's and b's).  For each i, set of valid suffixes after a^i are different, so each a^i must lead to a different state and the number i is unbounded.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem

Comment: Yeah, I got my definitions mixed up I think. For some reason I thought acceptance meant simply that all words in the language would be valid for a DFA. Which is wrong!